# Nativescript testing with Testbed not working

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

For the project we are currently starting up using native script with angular2, unit testing is essential to us. So I first tried to implement some simple for the given example of Groceries, just to get the hang of it. The very simple tests such as testing if the verification of the email-adres works fine and was not much work to implement.
As soon as I started with complexer test, I only get errors as soon as Testbed is involved.

Here is the most simple staring implementation I have of it with Testbed:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import 'nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript';
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserService } from "../../../shared/user/user.service";

declare var describe: any;
declare var expect: any;
declare var it: any;
declare var beforeEach: any;

describe('UserService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [UserService]
        });
    }); 

    it("just testing", () => {
        console.log('hier');
        expect(false).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

And this is the sort of error I get as soon as I run it:

```
sampleGroceries[66839]: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tests/shared/user/user.service.spec.js:13:20: hier
NativeScript / 10.0 (10.0; iPhone) A suite contains spec with an expectation FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent') in file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js (line 385)
resetFakeAsyncZone@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js:385:22
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js:1255:31
attemptSync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
execute
fn
attemptAsync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
fn
attemptAsync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
execute
execute
runTests@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:216:23
file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:187:101
tick@file:///app/tns_modules/timer/timer.js:17:26
UIApplicationMain@[native code]
start@file:///app/tns_modules/application/application.js:234:26
anonymous@file:///app/./tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app.js:3:18
evaluate@[native code]
moduleEvaluation@[native code]
[native code]
promiseReactionJob@[native code]
NativeScript / 10.0 (10.0; iPhone) UserService just testing FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent') in file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js (line 385)
resetFakeAsyncZone@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js:385:22
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/../bundles/core-testing.umd.js:1255:31
attemptSync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
execute
fn
attemptAsync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
fn
attemptAsync
run
onComplete
clearStack
run
complete
clearStack
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
execute
fn
attemptAsync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
fn
attemptAsync
run
execute
queueRunnerFactory
execute
execute
runTests@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:216:23
file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:187:101
tick@file:///app/tns_modules/timer/timer.js:17:26
UIApplicationMain@[native code]
start@file:///app/tns_modules/application/application.js:234:26
anonymous@file:///app/./tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app.js:3:18
evaluate@[native code]
moduleEvaluation@[native code]
[native code]
promiseReactionJob@[native code]
NativeScript / 10.0 (10.0; iPhone): Executed 2 of 2 (2 FAILED) ERROR (0.02 secs / 0.002 secs)
```

I tried various things like import zone.js/dist/proxy.js and a lot of other stuff without succes.

Does anybody know what I am missing? How do you implement it correctly so that unit test would work for native script with testbed???

Comment: I ran into this error too. Does anyone have a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

To use TestBed with NativeScript you must use the NativeScript version of TestBed. This is because NativeScript is not running in the browser; it's views are native and we are not dealing with html.

There is some documentation here: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/testing/testing

And here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/testing/testing#testbed-integration

Once you have integrated the NativeScript TestBed, most of the functions are similar to Angular's implementation of TestBed e.g. componentFixture